# Blender 2.79b Grease pencil brush hotkeys not working (Windows7 ,64bit)

Tags: grease-pencil

So,while using Blender 2.79b Grease pencil brushes  (on Windows7 ,64bit) , I tried using the number (1,2,3....)default hotkeys assigned to them  and found they were not working.Then I changed the hotkeys to other unique keys so that they didn't match with other operators  still the brush hotkeys where not working.
Any solution?

Comment: What does make you think the problem is with hotkeys? Could it be that you are trying to access the brushes in wrong context? E.g not pressing D or E for certain GP modes, or trying to access brushes in Object mode

Comment: Tried everything, still the hotkeys don't respond.

Comment: More context is required. Screenshots of what mode are you in when trying to use brushes, what tools are available in the Toolshelf. Also when doing screenshots undo all changes to hotkeys to default ones. If default hotkeys aren't working then either you try to use the tool wrong or there's a problem with the keys on the keyboard.

Comment: OK,so I reinstalled the software   ,now it works fine.Thanks everyone for the reply.

Comment: There were some old files from previous versions of blender lying in Program files directory.Deleting them and reinstalling blender worked.

Comment: I suggest you leaving an answer in the special field below with details of what problem you had and how you solved it. This could help other people with the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally ,there were some old files from previous versions of blender lying in Program files directory.Deleting them and reinstalling blender worked and now grease pencil shortcuts work.